# Mount compressed disk image or clone with dd respecting free space

Tags: dd

I intend to mount locally an image obtained as a clone through `dd`. The image is corresponds to a mSATA disk of 512GB of storage, with a minimum version of Ubuntu barely configured. So usefully, really the content with data should not be larger than 3GB.

However, for resource and space efficiency I have compressed with gz the image with the following command:

```
dd bs=64K if=/dev/sdd conv=sync,noerror status=progress | gzip -c  > /image.img.gz
```

Where `/dev/sdd` is the disk in question. Which has created a 2.4GB compressed image, that if I try to decompress, of course, it will occupy the original 512GB.

To burn the compressed image to another disk I use the following command:

```
gunzip -c /image.img.gz | dd bs=64K of=/dev/sdy status=progress
```

However, I do not want to burn it to another disk now but mount it on my own system (with the mount utility), since I want to make some changes and configurations before it burns to a specific disk. But I don't have enough space on the disk (512GB).

Is there a way to mount it directly compressed? and in case not, any way to clone the disk making it occupy less?

Comment: you can try your luck with `dd conv=sparse`. otherwise you'll need squashfs or any filesystem with transparent compression/deduplication. probably not using dd here at all would have been a better choice. [also `conv=sync,noerror` is known to cause data corruption](https://superuser.com/a/1075837/195171) if it actually encounters a read error so don't use that...

Comment: Somewhat related, for future reference: [Clone only space in use from hard disk](https://superuser.com/q/1097210/432690).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image was compressed very well, so probably it contains many null bytes (a SSD after `fstrim` usually returns null bytes for sectors temporarily unused by the filesystem). If it's the case, you should try to decompress your `.gz` archive to a sparse file. The target filesystem must support sparse files for this to work. An example command:

```
gunzip -c /image.img.gz | cp --sparse=always /dev/stdin /path/to/store/image.img
```

Instead of `cp --sparse=always` you can use `dd conv=sparse`, but mind this: [*Why didn't `dd conv=sparse` save space as I expected?*](https://superuser.com/q/1136357/432690)

Run `watch ls -hls /path/to/store/image.img` in another console and observe the 1st and the 6th column. The number in the 6th column will grow to about 512GB; the number in the 1st column should stay moderately low, this is how much space the decompressed image takes on the disk.

Then use `kpartx` to gain access to partitions within `/path/to/store/image.img`; or `fdisk -l /path/to/store/image.img` (or `gdisk -l …`) and `mount -o offset=…` to mount directly from the image. If your `/dev/sdd` was a superfloppy (no partitions within, just a filesystem) then you just `mount /path/to/store/image.img /the/mountpoint`.

Comment: All correct, now I have the sparsed image occupying 5GB instead of 510GB. It is only failing me now when it comes to mounting it, but since I consider that it is no longer part of this question, I tell it here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/731592/how-to-mount-a-sparsed-disk-image