# How to mount a sparsed disk image

Tags: mount, fdisk, sparse-files, gdisk, kpartx

I have an image of the mSATA SSD disk of a PC. The disk contains the operating system and has a capacity of 512GB.

I do not have that free storage, so I have cloned the disk into an image with `dd` compressing it with `gz`, and later according to the answer of [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/731496/373893), I have copied the sparsed content so that it occupied little.

This has worked correctly, resulting in a 512GB image occupying less than 5GB on disk.

As a summary of what has been done:

```
# dd bs=64K if=/dev/sdd conv=sync,noerror status=progress | gzip -c  > /image.img.gz
# gunzip -c /image.img.gz | cp --sparse=always /dev/stdin mini.img
# ls -lhs
4,8G -rw-------  1 balon users 477G ene 13 10:54 mini.img
2,3G -rw-r--r--  1 balon users 2,3G ene 11 08:32 minimal-industrial-pc.img.gz
```

So far, everything is correct. The problem comes when I intend to mount the image (since I want to cage myself in it and make some changes about the file system).

I have tried the following:

1. `fdisk`

```
# fdisk -l mini.img
The size mismatch of the primary master boot record (GPT PMBR) (1000215215!= 1000215295) will be corrected by writing.
The backup GPT table is not at the end of the device.
Disk mini.img: 476,94 GiB, 512110231552 bytes, 1000215296 sectors
Units: sectores de 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disc label type: gpt
Disk identifier: 74BC899D-E8BA-4C70-B82D-6F4E8F6343A3

Device    Start   End        Sectors   Size   Type
mini.img1 2048    2203647    2201600   1G     EFI System
mini.img2 2203648 6397951    4194304   2G     Linux file system
mini.img3 6397952 1000212479 993814528 473.9G Linux file system
```

2. `kpartx`

```
# kpartx -a -v mini.img
GPT:Primary header thinks Alt. header is not at the end of the disk.
GPT:Alternate GPT header not at the end of the disk.
GPT: Use GNU Parted to correct GPT errors.
add map loop1p1 (254:4): 0 2201600 linear 7:1 2048
add map loop1p2 (254:5): 0 4194304 linear 7:1 2203648
add map loop1p3 (254:6): 0 993814528 linear 7:1 6397952
```

In this case there seems to be no problems mounting `loop1p1` and `loop1p2`, but with `loop1p3, which I understand corresponds to the Ubuntu root system, there is no way.

3. `gdisk`

```
# gdisk -l mini.img
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.9.1

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.
Disk mini.img: 1000215296 sectors, 476.9 GiB
Sector size (logical): 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 74BC899D-E8BA-4C70-B82D-6F4E8F6343A3
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 1000215182
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 4717 sectors (2.3 MiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048         2203647   1.0 GiB     EF00
   2         2203648         6397951   2.0 GiB     8300
   3         6397952      1000212479   473.9 GiB   8300
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: (1) Hint: `LC_ALL=C mount …` would probably give you the exact English equivalent of this `debe ser …` and you can post it here where we expect English. (2) Does the message mean `you must be superuser to use mount`? Were you root when trying to mount `/dev/mapper/loop1p3`? (3) What is the output of `file -s /dev/mapper/loop1p3`? (use `sudo` if needed). (4) For future reference: without `kpartx` a command to mount is `mount -o offset="$((512*6397952))" mini.img /some/mountpoint`. (I don't think `kpartx` is the problem though.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image is likely corrupt due to the flags you used on `dd`. If you can repeat the process never use `dd`. Instead,

```
gzip </dev/sdd >/.../sdd.img.gz
zcat /.../sdd.img.gz | cp --sparse=always /dev/stdin mini.img
```

Tightening this up more, if you don't actually need the compressed image just make a sparse copy directly from the disk:

```
cp --sparse=always /dev/sdd mini.img
```

If the disk `/dev/sdd` is in use while it's being copied the copy will likely fail integrity checks - the worst case is that you don't see them.

Comment: what `dd` flags are the problem here, out of interest?

Comment: `dd` is primarily the problem. After that, `conv=sync,noerror` which almost certainly doesn't do what you think it does. (It doesn't fill failed reads with zeros.)